# Spring boot: how to set a common path for multiple RestControllers

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I am using spring boot to write an api and I would like to map all my resources behind a common base path (/api in this case). However I don't want to annotate each RestController class to do this (by annotating it with @RequestMapping for example).
I have thought about the following solutions but they all have a down side that i would rather not want:

- Creating a base class (eg ApiRestController) and having all the other RestController inherit this one. This has as disadvantage that @Requestmapping on the class level isn't merged between the base and implementing classes.
- Annotating all the RestController but this leads to code duplication
- Changing the server.context-path property. This has as disadvantage that all endpoints will use this base path. Even the endpoints exposed by the actuator project.
- Using a custom DispatcherServlet and ServletRegistrationBean. But this seems to have the same effect as changing the server.context-path.

So does anyone know how to do this without the disadvantages the solutions have that i summed. The project will only expose a REST-based backend and will not server any static content (don't know if this influences the possible solutions). The Restcontrollers are also divided over multiple packages.

Thanks.

Comment: If I understood correctly, there is a Issue on Spring talking about this feature: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16336

Comment: The issue that @Dherik mentioned has been closed and I couldn't find out a solution. Did you find a way to resolve this?

Comment: For now I had to settle with this workaround, which places this specif path as a property in yml and use spEL - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35699678/5035525

Answer (score 13):

Why don't you put @RequestMapping("/api") on all RestControllers?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserApi {
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public String user() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to avoid this code duplication if possible (being very DRY ;)), there is always a change of forgetting it

Comment: If you forget, you receive an error and that's enough. In portuguese we have a word for it, "preciosismo".

Comment: This is not adding common context path for all controllers, this is adding each to each controller separately.

Comment: @MichałMargiel that's what I said.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to create your custom annotation which would include `@RestController` and `@RequestMapping`:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@RestConntroller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api" )
@interface MyController {

}
```

Comment: I think this would give the same problem if i put this annotation on a class and a "@RequesMapping" (because eg all the resources in that class are under the path /api/user), the two "@RequestMapping" annotations wouldn't be merged, or am I wrong in this?

Comment: If you put one annotation on a class and the other one on the method, they should be merged.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using @path annotation to consider multiple URI as single URI.

```
@Path("sampleresource/{Filepath:.*}")
public interface SampleResource {
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    @Path("/hello")
    public Response sayHello();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to a similar question.
[How to configure a default @RestController URI prefix for all controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801351/how-to-configure-a-default-restcontroller-uri-prefix-for-all-controllers/39716758#39716758)
You can create a custom annotation and just perform mappings based on it.